# How to store/create data with multiple dates for the same timetable

Tags: django, postgresql, timetable

I have a model of a timetable as below:-

```
class time_table(models.Model):

    username = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="username", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    sem_section = models.ForeignKey(sem_sections, db_column = "sem_section",on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    subject_id = models.ForeignKey(subjects,db_column="subject_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    day_name = models.ForeignKey(days_ref, db_column = "days_ref",on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    hour_no = models.ForeignKey(hours, db_column = "hour_no",on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):

        ret = str(self.username) +' takes ' + str(self.sem_section) + " class " + str(self.subject_id) + " on " + str(self.hour_no) + " on " + str(self.day_name);

        return ret

    class Meta:

        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['sem_section', 'day_name', 'hour_no'], name='Allotment_check')
        ]
```

I have to create multiple records that repeat for each tuple that is inserted like if i insert a slot for monday 4th hour having some subject it must be created for multiple recurring dates of the whole year or semester.
Any sugestions on how to tweak the code or any extra code to add to achieve this goal.
I am using Postgres for database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's bulk_create along with (python) list comprehension to create multiple objects.

Comment: Can you just give a code snippet for my code above such that recurring mondays will have the same class.